# Is my kitten's breathing normal?

Tags: cats, health

I read online that a normal breathing rate for kittens is 30-40 breaths per minute, but it looks like my kitten's breathing at a much faster rate than that--more like 60 breaths per minute. Is this something I should be worried about, or is he okay?

He's around 4 months old, and I adopted him a few days ago.

[Video here](https://streamable.com/ipirys)

Comment: the breathing of your cat looks normal in the video so you can relax,it is no sign of problems as it is now it is a bit fast but nothing unusual.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to look at is how many breaths your cat takes when resting or sleeping. It should be at about 20-30 a minute, but kittens and young cats will often breath a bit faster than this.

Source: https://sanbrunopet.com/pet-care-tips/monitoring-breathing-rate-dogs-cats

During the day when the cat is active, the breathing will be faster, often by a lot; what you need to look at is how fast the breathing slows down when your cat lays down to rest.

If the breathing doesn't slow down in 2 to 3 minutes when the cat is at rest, you might want your vet to take a look at him.

Rapid breath might be a sign of infection or heart anomalies, but your vet will look for this during the regular checkup of your cat.

Source: https://wagwalking.com/cat/condition/rapid-breathing

If your cat takes more than 40 breaths a minute over a long period of time when it is resting, you need to take him to the vet; heart anomalies are not uncommon in cats.